# How to measure the increase in violent crime between years?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, effect-size, large-data

I have crime data from my country, consisting of the counts of recorded crimes (split by various categories), as well as population data from census years. **I want to measure if there has been a statistically significant increase in violent crime between the last 2 census years.** I was wondering if anyone could provide feedback on my methodology to carry out this analysis:

- Lump various categories of crime (murder, assault, etc) into the
  "violent crime" category, such that I have a count of the total
  reported violent crimes in both years.
- Based on information provided with the dataset, I know that for
  incidents where multiple crimes are committed, only the most serious
  is recorded in the data - avoiding duplicate entries for the same
  incident with only 1 victim. For crimes with multiple victims, a
  crime is recorded for each of the victims.
- With this information, I used a "counting framework", that is, each
  person in the population (from the census data that year), is
  assigned a label of 0 or 1, depending on if they've been a victim of
  a violent crime or not - the sum of these labels is therefore the
  total number of violent crimes reported that year, and dividing that by the census population gives
  the probability of being a victim of a reported violent crime.
- I then carried out a 1-sided 2-sample t-test, measuring whether the
  probability of being a victim has increased between the 2 years.

This resulted in a very small p-value (order of 1e-150), due to the large sample sizes involved (the population of the country), although the effect size is very small ~0.01. Is this method correct? It seems odd that the effect size is so small, because when I look at the number of violent crimes per 100k population, there has been a ~30% increase between the 2 census years, so it seems like there should be a greater effect size.

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you saying if 30 violent crimes are reported in an area of 1,000 people, you know for sure 970 people were not victims of crime?

Comment: No, I'm saying they're not victims of a reported violent crime in this analysis. We're comparing rates of reported violent crime between years

Comment: I think you're missing my point, though I admit I said "not victims of crime" and meant "not victims of *violent* crime". The point is that these data sources are not harmonized and the analysis is guaranteed to boost power arbitrarily high. For instance, you presume you've done a whole population analysis, so why even report a $p$-value for that matter?

Comment: If I am traveling for work or school and a crime happens in area A but I live in area B according to the census, how do you assign non-crime victim status? It's also not clear how you prevent duplicating events... if subject A has a violent crime in January, and again in June, are you merging based on PHI to determine crime has occurred? Your description of calculating annual incidence is not actually calculating annual incidence.

Comment: Ok understood - you mean there may be conflict between the 2 separate sources of data for the population and reported crimes.

Comment: I see your point on the p-value - that I'm presuming to use the whole population rather than a sample. Is it not valid to look at it as trying to understand the probability histogram generating the data - that is, understanding if there is a statistically significant difference in the underlying probability histogram that generates violent crime events. Where the chance occurs due to random events such as "wrong place, wrong time" rather than chance sampling error.

Comment: Regarding location of the crime, this data covers the whole country, and we only look at the results for my country. As for duplicate events, each event is considered a separate incident - if someone is a victim of a violent crime in January and again in June, this is reported in the data as 2 separate events.

Comment: There is a strong case for quasipoisson models here. You may find a reference in Alan Agresti Categorical Data Analysis 2nd ed. ch. 5 I believe.

Comment: Although chances are @AdamO is right guessing what you did, I don't understand from your description how exactly you have run the t-test, and this would be needed to explain to you how the result came about and whether and why it's invalid. (Note that a two-sample t-test is not a standard test for comparing proportions.)

Comment: So, I would take the total number of violent crimes in year1 and divide by the population of the country in year1 to get P1, the probability of being a victim of a violent crime. Likewise for year2. I would then do a 1 sided 2 sample t test where HA is P1 > P2 and H0 is P1-P2 = 0 using these proportions (or means). Let me know if this clears things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the analysis is doable based on the description. But the simplest statistical point can be addressed. You say you do a "count" analysis, but you actually do a $t$-test based on 0/1 counts of individual annual incidence of crime (1=crime victim that year, 0 =not a crime victim that year).

In that case, if in 2020 there were 10 violent crimes among 10,000 people whereas in 2021 there were 20 violent crimes among 10,000 people, you seem to desire to estimate that crime has doubled. However, the t-test would show the proportion was 0.001 in 2020 and 0.002 in 2021 for an *absolute risk difference of* 0.001 or a 0.1% absolute change. $t$-tests model means and the mean is going to be small.

Modeling changes in rare and untoward circumstances usually requires that we measure the result on a log scale so that the effect estimate is a *relative risk difference*. You *could* use a logistic regression model since the odds ratio is approximately the relative risk ratio. In this case;

$$ OR = (20 / (10000 - 20)) / (10 / (10000 - 10) \approx 2$$

I think a far superior model would be a quasipoisson regression model, a generalization of the log linear model which is conservative with standard error calculation since the analysis sets are not truly independent between separate years (there are a lot of subjects who are just not going to be victims of crime, and so we model the variance as proportional to the mean and get valid inference).

Comment: Thank you for this reply. So besides the issues you mentioned earlier regarding data sources etc, the problem with the statistical method (2 sample t-test) boils down to the fact that violent crimes are rare events and require special treatment as opposed to a standard t-test.